# dict_1 = {"a":[5,2,55,17],"P":(11,121,222),"B":(37,53,71),"c":[45,92,50]} I have to remove those numbers are not prime and have to create a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested-loops

```
dict_1 = {"a":[5,2,55,17],"P":(11,121,222),"B":(37,53,71),"c":[45,92,50]}
l=[]
dict_prime={}
for i,j in dict_1.items():
    for k in j:
        for n in range(2,k):
            if k%n!=0:
                pass
            else:
                l.append(k)
                break
    
                for m,n in dict_1.items():
                    for v in n:
                        if v!=k:
                            print(v)
                            break
```

I have done this I append the items in the list to check the process. now I can't remove those elements present in this list

Comment: Don't remove the loser items.  Instead, build a new list with only the items you want to keep.  You should create an `is_prime` function to make the code easier to read.

Comment: What should the final result be for this input?

Answer (score 1):

Notice how much simpler the code is to read when I create an `is_prime` function:

```
import math

dict_1 = {"a":[5,2,55,17],"P":(11,121,222),"B":(37,53,71),"c":[45,92,50]}

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

dict_prime={}
for i,j in dict_1.items():
    dict_prime[i] = []
    for k in j:
        if is_prime(k):
            dict_prime[i].append(k)

print(dict_prime)
```

The final loop could actually be written even shorter:

```
dict_prime={}
for i,j in dict_1.items():
    dict_prime[i] = [k for k in j if is_prime(k)]
```

You could actually combine those 3 lines into one line, but I think that sacrifices readability.